# How to write a vertically centered asterisk in LaTex in a normal text?

Tags: text-decorations

In the [exercises of the C++PL (4th Edition)](http://www.stroustrup.com/4thExercises.pdf) I see that it is possible to write, for example, `(*1)`.

How can I achieve this in LaTeX? When I try the same sequence of characters as I just did before (in text in LaTeX), then it is rendered similar to: (*1)

Comment: On my computer, the two examples look the similar, with a raised star before a numeral 1. The position of the star seems to be a glyph variant, some tt fonts use a centred asterisk, not all.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What about `\textasteriskcentered` as in the following MWE?

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Here is a vertically centered star \textasteriskcentered{} while %
here is the normal star * filler text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `$\ast1$` in math mode to archive this result. This is a shorter function to the one described above.

[image]

Comment: Just $\ast$ seems to produce the asterisk, $\ast1$ produces *1.